React Native Expo App showing error after I build the apk file
It shows this error after I integrate my app with Razorpay. It works fine in emulator but not on the real device.
Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.

First Error before clicking on reload.
and when i click on reload the second error appears:
Could not connect to development server.

Try the following to fix the issue:

• Ensure that Metro is running

• Ensure that your device/emulator is connected to your machine and has USB debugging enabled - run 'adb devices' to see a list of connected devices

• Ensure Airplane Mode is disabled

• If you're on a physical device connected to the same machine, run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' to forward requests from your device • If your device is on the same Wi-Fi network, set 'Debug server host & port for device' in 'Dev settings' to your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server - e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081

URL: http://localhost:8081/.expo/.virtual-metro -entry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true& minify=false&app=com.ashurath.hungerhub& modulesOnly=false&runModule=true

Second Error page
It was running fine before I created the android folder but Razorpay was not working that time neither in Mobile or in Emulator. After i created the android folder and made some changes and build it works fine in emulator but not in physical device
This is my build.gradle file:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript { ext { buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '33.0.0' minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '21') compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '33') targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '33') kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.8.10' frescoVersion = findProperty('expo.frescoVersion') ?: '2.5.0'
   
 // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
    ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2')
    classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
}
}

allprojects { repositories { maven { // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android')) } maven { // Android JSC is installed from npm url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist')) }

    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
}

} // @generated begin expo-camera-import - expo prebuild (DO NOT MODIFY) sync-f244f4f3d8bf7229102e8f992b525b8602c74770 def expoCameraMavenPath = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo-camera/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../android/maven") allprojects { repositories { maven { url(expoCameraMavenPath) } } } // @generated end expo-camera-import

This is my eas.json
{ "cli": { "version": ">= 7.8.0" }, "build": { "development": { "developmentClient": true, "distribution": "internal" }, "preview": { "distribution": "internal", "ios":{ "simulator":true }, "android":{   
 "buildType": "apk"
  }
},
"production": {}
}, "submit": { "production": {} } }

This is my android/app/build.gradle:
apply plugin: "com.android.application" apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

def projectRoot = rootDir.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()

/**

This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.

By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need. */ react { entryFile = file(["node", "-e", "require('expo/scripts/resolveAppEntry')", projectRoot, "android", "absolute"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()) reactNativeDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile() hermesCommand = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/sdks/hermesc/%OS-BIN%/hermesc" codegenDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native/codegen/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile()

// Use Expo CLI to bundle the app, this ensures the Metro config // works correctly with Expo projects. cliFile = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@expo/cli')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()) bundleCommand = "export:embed"

/* Folders */ //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..' // root = file("../") //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native") //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/@react-native/codegen // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")

/* Variants */ //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'. //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants. // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]

/* Bundling */ //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'. // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]

// //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty. // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js) // //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle" // //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js' // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js") // //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands. //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle // extraPackagerArgs = []

/* Hermes Commands */ //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc' // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc" // //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map" // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"] }

/**

Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode. */ def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = (findProperty('android.enableProguardInReleaseBuilds') ?: false).toBoolean()

/**

The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)



For example, to use the international variant, you can use:

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'



The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data

allowing to use e.g. Date.toLocaleString and String.localeCompare that

give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that

this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default. */ def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android { ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

namespace 'com.ashurath.hungerhub'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.ashurath.hungerhub'
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"

    buildConfigField("boolean", "REACT_NATIVE_UNSTABLE_USE_RUNTIME_SCHEDULER_ALWAYS", (findProperty("reactNative.unstable_useRuntimeSchedulerAlways") ?: true).toString())
}
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        shrinkResources (findProperty('android.enableShrinkResourcesInReleaseBuilds')?.toBoolean() ?: false)
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
}

// Apply static values from gradle.properties to the android.packagingOptions // Accepts values in comma delimited lists, example: // android.packagingOptions.pickFirsts=/LICENSE,**/picasa.ini ["pickFirsts", "excludes", "merges", "doNotStrip"].each { prop -> // Split option: 'foo,bar' -> ['foo', 'bar'] def options = (findProperty("android.packagingOptions.$prop") ?: "").split(","); // Trim all elements in place. for (i in 0..<options.size()) options[i] = options[i].trim(); // [] - "" is essentially [""].filter(Boolean) removing all empty strings. options -= ""

if (options.length > 0) {
    println "android.packagingOptions.$prop += $options ($options.length)"
    // Ex: android.packagingOptions.pickFirsts += '**/SCCS/**'
    options.each {
        android.packagingOptions[prop] += it
    }
}

}

dependencies { // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android") implementation project(':react-native-razorpay') implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:17.0.0' def isGifEnabled = (findProperty('expo.gif.enabled') ?: "") == "true"; def isWebpEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.enabled') ?: "") == "true"; def isWebpAnimatedEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.animated') ?: "") == "true"; def frescoVersion = rootProject.ext.frescoVersion

// If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
if (isGifEnabled || isWebpEnabled) {
    implementation("com.facebook.fresco:fresco:${frescoVersion}")
    implementation("com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:${frescoVersion}")
}

if (isGifEnabled) {
    // For animated gif support
    implementation("com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:${frescoVersion}")
}

if (isWebpEnabled) {
    // For webp support
    implementation("com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:${frescoVersion}")
    if (isWebpAnimatedEnabled) {
        // Animated webp support
        implementation("com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:${frescoVersion}")
    }
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
}
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")

if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}

}

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

